# Disposing a data reader when constructing it by value vs reference

Tags: c#, reference, dispose, datareader

Rookie question about when a data reader actually gets released when it’s constructed in a class using `ref` vs. var.  I’ve been testing this today and the results are puzzling me a bit – hoping to get this clear in my head.

I have a class that I use for fetching data via ODBC from numerous remote servers but I need to restrict how many ODBC connections are open to each server I'm attached to – so I’m being careful about properly disposing data readers when I’m done with them before opening another.  Short version is I have a method called `FillDataReader` that takes a data reader object, and fills it based on your query and passes it back.

If I pass it using `ref` and dispose the data reader from the calling side, all is well.  The connection is released immediately and the client side can get another data reader filled without burning a connection.  However if I pass by value, the resource is not released and if I open another data reader from the client side I now have two connections to that server.

Conceptually I get the difference – with `ref` only a single address is being used as it’s passing a “pointer to a pointer” and the dispose releases that resource. OK, but even if passing by value and doing an explicit dispose on the client side what, exactly, is holding the resource?  I’d rather pass by value here so I can use the nifty `using` construct on the client side but more importantly I want to understand better what’s happening here. In a nutshell here’s what it looks like

[DB fetch class]

```
public bool FillDataReader(string pQueryString, ref System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader pDataReader, out string pErrorReason)
        {
(uses a connection object that’s been established at class construction time and stays up all the time)
...
            try
            {
                pDataReader = _Command.ExecuteReader();
            }
...
         }

[Calling class]

strSQL = "SELECT Alias, ObjectID, FROM vw_GlobalUser";
               if (ServerList[currentServer].DatabaseFunctions.FillDataReader(strSQL, ref drTemp, false, out strErrorReason) == false)
               ….

    drTemp.Dispose();

(at this point the connection is released to the server)
```

However if I take the `ref` out at the point of Dispose in the calling class the connection is not released.  It goes away eventually but I need it gone immediately (hence the call to dispose).

So is the fill function in the DB fetch class hanging onto a reference to the allocated space on the heap somehow?  I’m not sure I understand why that is – understood it’s using another copy of the address to the data reader on the stack to reference the data reader object on the heap there but when it goes out of scope, isn’t that released?  Maybe I need more coffee…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your calling code needs to receive the reference to release the object, you do need a `ref` (or `out`). Otherwise the parameter is only passed to the method, but not back, so that the `drTemp` isn't updated with the data reader created in the `FillDataReader` method.

Note that you may want to change the signature as follows to make the intention more clear:

```
public Result TryGetDataReader(string pQueryString, out System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader pDataReader)
```

Changes that I propose:

- Introduced the naming convention with "Try", which is common for this type of method
- Made the pDataReader an `out`, since it doesn't need to be initialized when calling the method
- Introduced a "Result" type, which should carry the success information and the error message (if any)

Comment: Thanks - making it an out makes sense, as does the use of the result object (had that on my to-do list already) - not sure I understand the comment about a naming convention with "Try" though

Comment: Methods that don't throw exceptions but "try" to perform an operation are typically named this way. Good examples are `Dictionary.TryGetValue()` and all the `TryParse()` methods on the simple types such as `int`, `long`, etc.

Comment: ah, ok - I get you - that makes sense.  Finished updating everything this afternoon and I'll change some of the names around to bring them in line - seems to be working dandy, just need to do some load testing and make sure all is well with lots of connections flying.  Thanks much for your input.